# How to handle data if majority equals zero? Data cleaning

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-analysis, data-cleaning

I'm a beginner and I am exploring TMDB 10000 Movie Dataset, I found out the following for budget and revenue columns:

```
b_0 = df[df['budget']==0].shape[0]/df.shape[0]*100
print('percentage of zero budget movies: ',b_0,'%')
```

percentage of zero budget movies:  52.425218591808566 %

```
b_r_0 = df[(df['revenue']==0) & (df['budget']==0)].shape[0]/df.shape[0]*100
```

percentage of zero revenue and budget movies:  43.26737229636448 %

```
r_0 = df[df['revenue']==0].shape[0]/df.shape[0]*100
print('percentage of zero revenue movies: ',r_0,'%')
```

percentage of zero revenue movies:  55.37045559134837 %

I know for sure that budget/revenue cannot equal zero, the statistics calculated ( mean, median, quartiles) are biased due to zero values so I can't use them for replacement and I can't drop over 40% of data.
How can I fix this?

data source: https://www.google.com/url?q=https://d17h27t6h515a5.cloudfront.net/topher/2017/October/59dd1c4c_tmdb-movies/tmdb-movies.csv&sa=D&ust=1532469042115000

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To know what is the best solution you must understand the real world where the data is coming from.

Mean or Median is usually the best.

You better first replace zeros with Null and then fill the Nulls with either median or mean.

If you need the code to do that - let me know

Comment: If I fill in the null values with median or mean, wouldn't I be copying same values to the other half of data (originally zero) ? Will my data be reliable then?

Comment: This is the common practice and the best you can do. Another alternative is to fill in the Nulls with mean/median of a more relevant portion of the population. E.g. fill it with mean of movies from the same ganer

Comment: great! thank youuu :)